# why won't mysql accept connections from local programs?

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I am getting a `"Host 'mydomain.com' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"` error whenever a program on my CentOS 7 server tries to access the MySQL/MariaDB database located on the same machine.  When I type `hostname` into the terminal, it replies with `mydomain.com`.

The complete stack trace is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2316)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at mainpackage.TestJDBC.main(TestJDBC.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'mydomain.com' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2334)
... 13 more
```

This server has been running applications with local database connections for some time.  The error occurred after I started to install OpenVPN on the server using [the instructions in this tutorial.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7)  I have since reversed almost all the commands from the tutorial, with the exception of certain script calls whose inverse functions are not known.  The error persists after the steps taken so far.

**What do I need to change in order to get MySQL connections to be accepted locally again?**

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**EDIT#1**

As per @Dan's request, `/etc/hosts` has not changed and thus remains:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
192.96.215.22 mydomain.com mydomain
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

Also, the connection string from the app remains:  `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sometestdb?autoReconnect=true";`

**EDIT#2**

As per @sufado's suggestion, `I want to confirm that /etc/hosts` should be as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost mydomain.com
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
192.96.215.22 mydomain.com mydomain
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

Comment: Tell the application to use `localhost` as mysql server if they are on the same machine

Comment: Funny then. Did you change the 127.0.0.1 line from /etc/hosts? Did you change your hostname? Mysql makes a difference between localhost and the host's fqdn and there are separate privileges set for each of them

Comment: It may just be a copy and paste error, but the first line of your hosts file is missing a 1. It should be 127.0.0.1. Anyway, add your `mydomain.com` to that line as well, then as Ricardo mentioned, make sure you have a 'youruser'@localhost user set up in the database.

Comment: I answered that in a comment under Ricardo's answer. XXXX is a passwword for that user, but you only need to put that if you're creating a brand new user. If 'root'@'mydomain.com' already exists, then it's not necessary when updating their privileges.

Comment: You also may want to issue a `flush hosts;` command, in case it's blocking that domain from connecting because of too many failed attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It clearly tells you:

```
Host 'mydomain.com' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

So what you need to do is add mydomain.com as a permited host in the users table, mysql database.  For example:

```
mysql> select host,user,password from user;
+--------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| host               | user         | password                                  |
+--------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost          | root         | *E99774447E62446243A1880831F8956BD8529ABF |
+--------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to root@"mydomain.com" IDENTIFIED BY 'XXXX' WITH GRANT OPTION;

mysql> select host,user,password from user;
+--------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| host               | user         | password                                  |
+--------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost          | root         | *E99774447E62446243A1880831F8956BD8529ABF |
| mydomain.com       | root         | *E99774447E62446243A1880831F8956BD8529ABF |
+--------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

You can also add just '%' and it would work for any host, its like a wildcard.  If you can't even get into the database to make the above changes, then you should change your hostname to localhost from mydomain.com.  Your allowed connections to the database should at the very least be the localhost ip 127.0.0.1

**UPDATE**:

```
You can disable DNS host name lookups by starting mysqld with the --skip-name-resolve option. However, in this case, you can use only IP addresses in the MySQL grant tables.
```

The reason your are getting the mydomain.com error is because the operating system is resolving the DNS host name lookup 127.0.0.1 to mydomain.com.  That is not a mysql issue but a networking issue.

Comment: The XXXX is the password. If you're having to ask a stranger over the Internet what you should put for a password, then I would go out on a limb here and say you're in over your head. Maybe you should spend the money on a consultant and make sure it gets done correctly. It'll be money well spent.

Comment: You should use matching passwords, same one as you are using for localhost, otherwise you will get mixed up at some time.  I updated my answer to reflect you can disable DNS lookups in case you need to troubleshoot this further.  Also, root is the username in my example, you should change that to reflect your actual user.

Comment: if you are talking about a row with host = localhost and user = root, then it is the password you created for the root mysql account.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for responding so quickly with a correct answer.